# Start an android application at a time chosen from the user

Tags: android, time

I'd like to do an application that starts at a specified time and that must continue until another specified time (but i want to let the user to change these times inside the application). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you have to create an background service in your app which runs continuously either your app is running or not, and implement a timer or alarm manager to set the time at which you want to open your application and also close the application with the same technique.

Comment: Do you have some examples (if you don't have any example, i'll search them myself)?

Comment: That is my own concept which I implemented in my own application so tell me which concept's code you need, so that i can share you that piece of code from my application.